# enabling loopback NAT

Tags: router, modem, nat, loopback

I have a Qwest Aciontec Q1000 modem/router combo, which does *not* support loopback. I run a webserver on the LAN, and when I'm on the LAN, I can only access it by its local IP 192.168.0.201. When I'm outside the LAN, I can access the machine by typing mm.example.com. I can do this because I have a no-ip account that points to my WAN IP, and I have port forwarding set up.

When I'm on my laptop, I have to edit my /etc/hosts file such that mm.example.com points to 192.168.0.201. Then, when I leave the WAN, I have to comment that out.

Can I just purchase a router that supports loopback so that I can access my webserver on the LAn by visiting mm.example.com or do I need to purchase a new modem as well?

Comment: What are you precisely changing in the hosts file?

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you are trying to do? The question is not clear as to what you mean by "loopback" in this context. Are you referring to NAT Reflection?

Comment: I run a server on my local network. On the LAN, I can access it at 192.168.0.201. I have port forwarding set up so when I'm outside the LAN, I can access it at mm.example.com. If I'm on the LAN with the server, I can't access it at mm.example.com because my router doesn't support loopback. Consequently, I have to edit my hosts file to direct mm.example.com to 192.168.0.201 and when I'm outside the LAN, I have to comment that out.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expanded explanation provided in your comment.

Comment: It sounds like you have misconfigured your webserver and/or the access in your router.

Comment: no. my webserver is configured properly. Perhaps you'd like to explain why you think it is misconfigured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch your Q1000 to be just a modem, then you can use a router that supports loopback NAT and that should solve your problem. To do this, go to `Advanced IP Configuration` and check `RFC 1483 Transparent Bridging`. Note that you will need to configure the new router to perform whatever authentication and handshaking your ISP requires, such as PPPoE or PPPoA. (Typically, nothing is required.)

The directions for the Actiontec Q1000 specifically can be found here: http://foxsys.blogspot.com/2011/10/qwest-actiontec-q1000-in-rfc-1483.html

Comment: I think its worth mentioning after I performed this on a CenturyLink modem the unit will no longer hand out IP addressees.  To access the modems GUI you'd need to deal with the fact your modem could be on 192.168.0.x and your new Router now using PPPoE with your account could be on 192.168.1.x (for example).  I've used TomatoUSB before to allow me to access the subnet before, but its something to call out from a functionality standpoint.  You'll either need to hardwire into the modem and handset your IP on your computer to access it, or figure out the routing/firewall to access it.

Answer (score 1):

So the feature you want is not on all routers, but it is needed for anything that is using NAT. If your modem is bridged, you do not need to worry about this feature. If your modem is in routed mode and you have a double-NAT situation, then you have a far more complex setup than is necessary (only use one device to NAT, but make sure it is one that can do NAT reflection/loopback).

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try, works really well for me.

http://www.mobilenetswitch.com/

Configure IP Addressing, Wi-Fi settings, Proxy Server, Drive Mappings, Default Printer, Dynamic outgoing (SMTP) mail server, Time Zone and much more for each location you use your machine.

---

it dynamically switches the hosts file too.  ;)